# Is Dart integrated with SASS?

Tags: sass, dart

After finally becoming more intimate with AngularDart (2.0), I decided to throw SASS into the relationship. It appears the SASS devs are also coming over to Dart [SASS to Dart](http://blog.sass-lang.com/posts/1022316-announcing-dart-sass) (two months ago).

Knowing that, the `@Component( styleUrls: 'style.sass')` doesn't appear to recognize the **.sass** or **.scss** extensions. Is there any knowledge or update on a timeline or expectancy to compatibility? Hell, maybe even a Dart pub for SASS (I feel like the latter might be here, but I glossed over it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dart 2**
In Dart 2 with `build_runner` just add

```
dev_dependencies:
  sass_builder: ^1.1.2
```

to `pubspec.yaml`

**Dart 1**

Use instead

```
@Component( styleUrls: 'style.css')
```

and add a sass transformer to your `pubspec.yaml`

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_sass_transformer

```yml
dependencies:
  dart_sass_transformer: ^0.5.0
transformers:
  - dart_sass_transformer:
```

then `style.sass` or `style.scss` will automatically be transformed to `style.css` and made available to Angular components

You need to run `pub get --packages-dir` until https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/pull/53 becomes available.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the downvote. The question was really about sass integration with Dart. I knew the solution to the @Component already (I was using css, transformed from scss using `sass --watch`). 

I'll check out the pub package and keep watching the github page. That was really what I wanted to know.